# Reference child column in Telerik grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I'm unable to successfully reference a child grid's column data when creating a `ClientTemplate` for a column in the child's grid.

This works just fine and shows true/false correctly:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.Completed).Title("Completed").Width(100);
```

This does not work:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.Completed).Title("Completed").Width(100).ClientTemplate(
                @"# if (Completed == true) { #" +
                "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Images/") + "checked.png' alt='quest icon' />" +
                "# } else { #" +
                "#: Completed #" +
                "# } #"
            );
```

The value, `Completed`, is always null therefore the `else` block is always hit and my Completed column just shows null for each row's value.

If I reference a parent grid column within else block I get the correct values so it seems as I'm missing something on how to reference the child columns.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I found the answers about 20 minutes after I posted.  You must escape the hash symbols in a nested grid.  Credit here:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/conditional-client-template-in-razor-hierarchical-grid